# order the bar chart values in apache zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin v0.5.6 on EMR. I am unable to get the bar chart sorted by the metric I am charting. As a dummy example I want the bar chart to show col2 ordered -

```
sc.parallelize(Range(0,10).map(e=>(e,e*e))).toDF("col1","col2").registerTempTable("temptable")

%sql select * from temptable order by col2 asc
```

or

`%sql select * from temptable order by col2 desc`

has no effect on the chart produced. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need the answer now, but still posting for others.
you have some problem in the dollar symbol try typing it by keyboard and first execute the first line and make sure you have not clicked on the table.

%sql 
select * from temptable order by col2 asc

Comment: "you have some problem in the dollar symbol try typing it by keyboard and first execute the first line and make sure you have not clicked on the table." I faced the same issue while working on the zeppelin notebook where the % sign was somehow encoded differently when copy and pasted from some web resource.